cannot access elements when using x-for
I made this code to get a json file and display a field from each of the elements
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<script>
  function note(a) {
      console.log(a);
      return a;
  }
</script>

<div x-data="{ bios: [] }",
     x-init="bios = note(await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/bios.json')).json())">
  <template x-for="h in bios">
    <p>member</p>
    <p x-text="h.Name"></p>
  </template>
</div>

when it loads, the console has the json file in it, but the page just has the word member as many times as there are elements and nothing else

why not put the note() function inside your x-data? also, since you're awaiting fetch, you should probably also make note() async and await that too.

The <template> tag for x-for requires a single root element, try so:
<template x-for="h in bios">

    <div>
        <p>member</p>
        <p x-text="h.Name"></p>
    </div>

</template>

Here you can find the related documentation
